# SQL check day of week

Tags: sql, oracle

How to check if it's a weekend in SQL?
I know I can convert `sysdate` to a number using this

```
 SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual;

 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')
```

But I'm not really sure how to check if today is a 6 or 7.

Comment: You can use this expression in a condition. Could you elaborate where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: I can't really, I'm trying to learn PLSQL doing assignments, and one of them simply asks me to check whether it's a weekend or not. So yeah, basically, I'm asking whether I can save the current day into a variable somehow so I can test it?

Comment: You're basically saying that I can do this?  IF  SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual; TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') == 7 THEN?

Comment: You can test the current day without saving anything into a variable. Try it out and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `TO_CHAR` with the `D` format model for this as it is dependant on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter.

For example, when `SYSDATE = 2018-09-10` (a Monday):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'D' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs `1` but the same query in a different territory:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America';
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'D' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs `2`.

Instead, you can use `TRUNC` and the `IW` format model:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) FROM DUAL
```

Outputs `0` for Monday (and `1` for Tuesday ... `6` for Sunday) and is independent of the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting.

So you could filter this to give weekends as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) IN ( 5, 6 )
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  SYSDATE - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) >= 5
```

If you want the days 1-indexed for consistency with your expected output from `TO_CHAR` (rather then 0-indexed) then just add 1 to the value.

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate` is a pseudo column. You don't need to query it, you can evaluate it directly:

```
IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') IN ('6', '7') THEN
    -- Do something
END IF;
```

Comment: This will only work if your `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter is set to a territory where Monday is the first day of the week. If you run this query in an international environment then you will find that in certain territories, such as America, this will return Friday and Saturday (since Sunday is the first day of the week for that territory).

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the ambiguous `'D'` format as this varies between territories (the week starts after the weekend where I live), and use

```
if to_char(sysdate,'fmDY','nls_date_language=English') like 'S%'
then
```

Regarding the `'D'` format, unfortunately `to_char` doesn't let you specify `nls_territory` inline, so without an explicit `alter session` command, it will rely on the session settings at runtime. I've seen production bugs due to this, where the same code worked in London but failed in New York.

Answer (score 0):

And here's the logic in a reusable function, but flipped to ask "Is it a weekday?" (not a weekend). You could add a parameter for the start day of the weekdays (2 is the default in Oracle; Sunday is day #1).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_weekday (date_in IN DATE) 
   RETURN BOOLEAN 
IS 
BEGIN 
   RETURN TO_CHAR (date_in, 'D') BETWEEN 2 AND 6; 
END; 
/

DECLARE 
   l_date   DATE := DATE '2018-09-10'; 
BEGIN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('If your weekend is Saturday and Sunday....'); 

   FOR indx IN 1 .. 7 
   LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 
            TO_CHAR (l_date, 'FMDay, Month DD YYYY') 
         || ' is ' 
         || CASE WHEN NOT is_weekday (l_date) THEN 'not ' END 
         || 'a weekday'); 
      l_date := l_date + 1; 
   END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

Try it in LiveSQL: 
    https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_G8NQSY6NP48NPJX96RLQ51SUE.html

Comment: This is slightly misleading - `2` is not the default for Monday since the default for Monday varies depending on your `NLS_TERRITORY` setting. If your `NLS_TERRITORY` is America then , yes, the first day of the week is Sunday but if your `NLS_TERRITORY` is set to much of Europe (i.e. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';`), the first day of the week is Monday and `TO_CHAR( a_monday_date, 'D' )` will be 1.